# How to get name of gnu indirect function using dladdr?

Tags: c++, gnu, elf

I can not get the gnu extension to elf with indirect functions to work with `dladdr`.

In the example below `fabs` and `sin` are two dynamic functions in `libm`, where `sin` is also an indirect function. Looking up `fabs` from its pointer works well, but `sin` is not found. I have tried various flags to `dlopen` and `-rdynamic` without success.

The debugger shows how `sin` is evaluated from from a `gnu-indirect-function variable` to `__sin_avx`.

Am I missing something here or are indirect functions not supported by `dladdr`?

```
/*
    compiled with g++-5 -fPIC -ldl
*/

#include <cmath>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>

char const * name (void * arg)
{
    void * h = dlopen (NULL, RTLD_LAZY);

    if (h)
    {
        Dl_info res;
        int status = dladdr (arg, & res);
        dlclose (h);

        if (status && res.dli_sname && arg == res.dli_saddr)
            return res.dli_sname;
    }

    return "";
}

int main ()
{
    std::cout << fabs (0.0) << " " << name ((void *) fabs) << std::endl; // found
    std::cout << sin  (0.0) << " " << name ((void *) sin ) << std::endl; // not found
}
```

Comment: Interesting, manages to work if you remove `-fPIC`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something here or are indirect functions not supported by dladdr?

Ok, this one was interesting.

So ifuncs work by replacing original function address (in this case `sin`) with the one it's resolved to by dynamic linker on current platform. `sin` can be resolved to one of 4 implementations depending on CPU capabilities:

```
libm_ifunc (__sin, (HAS_ARCH_FEATURE (FMA4_Usable) ? __sin_fma4 :
                    HAS_ARCH_FEATURE (AVX_Usable)
                    ? __sin_avx : __sin_sse2));
weak_alias (__sin, sin)
```

Now each of `__sin_XXX` is an internal Glibc function which is *not* *exported* from `libm.so` and that's why `dladdr` fails to find it.

So the answer is basically no, `dladdr` does not work well with ifuncs...

> manages to work if you remove -fPIC

This happens because whenever you compile w/o `-fPIC` compiler knows that current source file will go to main executable and so runtime function address is guaranteed to resolve to executable's PLT entry. So instead of loading it from GOT, it simply passes PLT address to `name` and `dladdr` then happily locates `sin` in executable's symtab.

EDIT:

Confirmed by Glibc folks [here](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2017-01/msg00010.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did find some [posts](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2016-08/msg00138.html) about ifunc and visibility, but the subject is pretty new to me. As a work-around, is there any way to refer to the original indirect function, the one with the `__attribute__ ifunc`?

Comment: I personally don't know any easier way than manually parsing the GOT table (e.g. described [here](http://vxheaven.org/lib/vrn00.html#c6)) but that's quite an undertaking. You can try asking in [libc-help](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/).

Comment: And [here](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2017-01/msg00010.html) is the answer to my question on libc-help. In short, information on original ifunc symbol name is lost when resolved to its implementation.

Regarding parsing the GOT - pardon my assembly - but from what I can read from the generated code, I'm not sure if ifuncs are not resolved already at program start, and not at first call. If so, there would be no opportunity to parse GOT for original ifunc address, right?

Comment: I've conducted a small experiment and it seems that ifuncs are resolved lazily. So _theoretically_ you could resolve them at program startup by analyzing GOT, until they are trashed by runtime linker. This of course won't work for ifuncs which are used in constructors.

Comment: My mistake using constant arguments above, the `sin@PLT` access was elided in the generated code which got me confused. Thanks for the effort.